# Why does this ActiveRecord query have different SQL output in Rails 3 vs Rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line in my code:

```
@total = FeedbackAnswer.count(:conditions => feedback_answers_conditions,
:joins => [:question, :feedback, {:feedback => :course}],
:group => 'question_id, courses.id').size
```

When calling this line in Rails 2.3.2 on Ruby 1.8.7 the query that I get is:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_all, question_id AS question_id, courses.id AS courses_id
FROM `feedback_answers` INNER JOIN `questions` 
ON `questions`.id = `feedback_answers`.question_id 
INNER JOIN `feedbacks` 
ON `feedbacks`.id = `feedback_answers`.feedback_id 
** INNER JOIN `feedbacks` feedbacks_feedback_answers 
ON `feedbacks_feedback_answers`.id = `feedback_answers`.feedback_id **
INNER JOIN `courses` 
ON `courses`.id = `feedbacks_feedback_answers`.container_id
WHERE (1=1 and feedbacks.container_type = "Course" 
and (Date(courses.start_date) >= '2013-05-27') 
and (feedback_answers.lesson_id is null) 
and (feedback_answers.answer_grade > 0)) 
GROUP BY question_id, courses.id
```

But when calling it from Rails 3.2.8 on Ruby 1.9.3 I get:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, question_id, courses.id AS question_id_courses_id 
FROM `feedback_answers` INNER JOIN `questions` 
ON `questions`.`id` = `feedback_answers`.`question_id` 
INNER JOIN `feedbacks` 
ON `feedbacks`.`id` = `feedback_answers`.`feedback_id` 
INNER JOIN `courses` 
ON `courses`.`id` = `feedbacks`.`container_id` 
WHERE (1=1 and feedbacks.container_type = "Course" 
and (Date(courses.start_date) >= '2013-05-27') 
and (feedback_answers.lesson_id is null) 
and (feedback_answers.answer_grade > 0)) 
GROUP BY question_id, courses.id
```

The difference is marked with a **.

Where does this difference come from? But most important, how do I get the 1.8.7 behaviour in my 1.9.3 code?

Comment: Same version of rails? It is odd, though are you seeing a different result?

Comment: Sorry, no. 1.8.7 is on rails 2.3.2, 1.9.3 is on 3.2.8

Comment: Wouldn't you expect that maybe two very different version of Rails might interact w/the database in a slightly different way? Why do you think the Ruby version affects this?

Comment: I've edited your question's title to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try change `joins` to `includes`.